# How to get only the selected lines from QLE in QCP context ? [Salesforce CPQ, QCP, JavaScript]

Tags: cpq, cpq-plugins

How to get only the selected lines from quote line editor in QCP context ?

We can create additional checkbox field on quote lines and refer that, but client wants to use standard checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The quoteline model doesn't include context about which quote lines have been selected. Your requirement doesn't really make sense since the QCP runs both from Edit Lines as well as anytime an edit is made to a calculating field. If you can edit your question and provide more context as to why you need this requirement, there could be another option.